# Finding memory leak and Understanding detached DOM tree

Tags: google-chrome, dom, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am checking for memory leak in application on idle condition using Chrome DevTools. memory timeline recording looks fine to me with no JS increase in JS heap after garbage collection. 
[image: memory timeline recording]

But When I take heap snapshot it I could see there are detached DOM trees.Does that mean memory leak is happening? If yes then why memory timeline not recording increase in heap size. Below is the screenshot for heap snapshot.
[image]

I would also like to understand the information it is showing for detached DOM tree. Bordered with red it says **[6803] in Document DOM tree / 10656 entries**. What is this number 6803 and 10656? Thanking in advance for any help.

Comment: You see a detached node you still have a reference to. You don't see changes in timeline because presumably it happened only once.

Comment: `[6803] in Document DOM tree / 10656 entries` means there is a collection of 10656 elements and the selected element is indexed as 6803.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the info. Wanted to ask one more thing. When I hover over HTMLDocument in native in HTMLDocument I see a list of properties like URL, active elements, ajaxq etc. When I hover over windows I see different objects in window. How should I proceed to locate the reference to node?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong charts in memory timeline tab. You need to choose the green checkbox for Nodes to investigate DOM memory leak.

There are 2 kinds of memory leak issues, JS memory leak and DOM memory leak. In the 1st picture, you are looking for JS memory leak, but in the memory snapshot, you checked DOM memory leak.